# COUNT QUERY IN DB2

Tags: sql, count, db2

In mainframe DB2, i have two tables TAB 1 and TAB 2. I have records in those tables like:

TAB 1:

```
AP_NBR  LOC_NBR
1000    1
1000    2
1000    3
```

TAB 2:

```
LOC_NBR ITM_ID
1   500
1   600
2   450
2   750
```

Her i need an output like below:

```
AP_NBR  COUNT(LOC_NBR)  COUNT(ITM_ID)
1000    3                     4
```

How to write COUNT query for this?
Can anyone please help me on this?

Comment: didnt get your logic. How did you get 4 on second row if you dont have any records with 1000 on second table?

Comment: Hi we have LOC_NBR in common for both the tables

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select t1.AP_NBR, count(distinct t1.LOC_NBR), count(distinct t2.ITM_ID)
from TAB1 t1 join TAB2 t2 on t1.LOC_NBR = t2.LOC_NBR
group by t1.AP_NBR
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
select * from
(select AP_NBR,COUNT(*) cnt_LOC_NBR from TAB1 group by AP_NBR)a,
(select COUNT(*) cnt_ITM_ID from TAB2 where LOC_NBR in 
(select LOC_NBR from TAB1))b
```

Comment: You're not correlating the rows in `a` with the rows in `b`, which means 1) you're going to end up with a cross-join and 2) most of those rows won't match the correct `LOC_NBR` rows together.  Personally, I'd hesitate to use this anyways, because 1) you're using the implicit-join (comma-separated `FROM` clause), which is usually considered deprecated, and 2) because you have an extra reference to `TAB1` that you don't really need.

Comment: Hi clockwork.. yes i am getting cross join. what to do in this case? please help